# Stackdriver Logs Don't Show Up on Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I've been using the Stackdriver Client API to write logs for Google Compute Engine. When I run gcloud logging logs list, I see my logs directory, but they don't show up on the logs interface: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer.

How do I get this to show up on the interface?

Comment: Are you sure that you are selecting the same project from the console and selecting your desired resource from logs interface to get the entries? [Here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#the_user_interfaces) you have the documentation for viewing logs from the console.

Comment: Can you try changing resources to global in dashboard. In dashboard you can find a dropdown list "Recently selected resources" which will have entries like (Audited Resource, Global, Google Project ....) there select "Global"